# android send data to fragment from activity

Tags: java, android

I have a map activity. When I click on the info window of the marker an intent will send the id to my fragment. In my map activity :

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(
    new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker m) {
            Intent nextScreen = new Intent (Map.this,
            PHDetail.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("test", "id");
            Callfor c = new Callfor();
            c.setArguments(bundle);
            startActivityForResult(nextScreen, 101);
        }
    });
```

In my fragment :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_call_for, container, false);
    TextView TXT = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.test);
    Bundle test = getArguments();
    if(test!=null){
        String d = test.getString("test", " "); 
        TXT.setText(d);
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

The problem is the bundle is null. How can I fix this?

This is my PHDetail FragmentActivity class :

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.phdetail);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        String id = intent.getStringExtra("test");
    }

            // Initialization :
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter  = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs :
        for (String tab_name : tabs){
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                        .setTabListener(this));
        }
        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {


    }

}
```

Comment: You are not starting a fragment, but an activity, after info window click !

Comment: the PHDetail class is a FragmentActivity

Comment: a [FragmentActivity](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fsupport%2Fv4%2Fapp%2FFragmentActivity.html&ei=8dHsUqemDMuS0QW9-YHIDg&usg=AFQjCNE9dlSgxqPBqw4MwuFoxv9GmqDXfQ&sig2=3aNw-2FjfbTKmrousDoEbQ) is not a fragment, but an Activity defined in android support in order to use fragments with `API < 11`.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

On your onTabSelected you need to create your Fragment, set the bundle and then do the transaction like this.

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view

    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("id", id);
    MyFragment fragment=new MyFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
    ft.commit();

}
```

**FIRST ANSWER**

The right way to pass values to other Activities like a FragmentActivity it´s adding those values to the intent that´s going to start them.

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(
    new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker m) {
            Intent nextScreen = new Intent (Map.this, PHDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra("test", "id");
            startActivityForResult(nextScreen, 101);
        }
    });
```

Then on your FragmentActivity called **PHDetail** you should get the values from the Intent.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent != null) {
    String id = intent.getStringExtra("test");
}
```

After that when you load your Fragment on your container view on PHDetail, you should add the Bundle and then do the transaction.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("test", "id");
Callfor c = new Callfor();
c.setArguments(bundle);
```

After that you'll be able to retrieve the values inside your Fragment like you stated above

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle         savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_call_for, container, false);
    TextView TXT = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.test);
    Bundle test = getArguments();
    if(test!=null){
        String d = test.getString("test", " "); 
        TXT.setText(d);
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: look at the PHDetail class

Comment: no, I ignored the Android Tab Layout with Swipeable Views and I use simple activity . thx ;)